# Resize and crop an image using ImageJ

Tags: java, image, imagej

I'm trying to resize and crop an image using ImageJ. Here's the code:

```
ImagePlus ip1 = IJ.openImage("_Pic.jpg");
ImagePlus ip2 = IJ.openImage("_Pic.jpg");

ImageProcessor imgP1 = ip1.getProcessor();
ImageProcessor imgP2 = ip2.getProcessor();

FileSaver fs1 = new FileSaver(ip1);
FileSaver fs2 = new FileSaver(ip2);

/* Trying to resize */
imgP1.resize(100); // also tried with width and height
fs1.saveAsJpeg("Resized.jpg");

/* Trying to crop */
imgP2.setRoi(100, 100, 200, 200);
imgP2.crop();
fs2.saveAsJpeg("Cropped.jpg");
```

Unfortunately, the newly created files are identical to the original one.

So far I've found out how to blur, smooth, invert, translate, rotate, ..., but these two are giving me hard time. Anybody has an idea?

Comment: Your example has many issues. The `resize()` method doesn't exist for class `ImagePlus`. `imgP12` and `imgP13` are not defined. etc.... I recommend using an IDE like [Eclipse](http://imagej.net/Developing_ImageJ_in_Eclipse) when developing Java code. Also, have a look at the [Javadoc](http://javadoc.imagej.net/ImageJ1/). Finally, for ImageJ-specific questions, it's best to ask on the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/).

Comment: @JanEglinger Thank you for your comment. I made a typo somehow... I'm using the `resize()` method on `imgP12` and `imgP13`, which should be `ImageProcessor` instances (instead of `imgP1` and `imgP2`). I'm using Eclipse and there were no syntax errors, I've only made a mistake while copying & pasting..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your [cross-posted question to the ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/t/cropped-and-resized-images-are-not-saved/5038?u=imagejan) was answered there by Stefan Helfrich:

> If you take a look at the [Javadocs for ImageProcessor](https://javadoc.imagej.net/ImageJ1/ij/process/ImageProcessor.html) you'll see that `resize()` as well as `crop()` return new `ImageProcessor` instances and do not operate on `this`. That's why you'll have to use the `ImagePlus.setProcessor(ImageProcessor)` method to add the returned ImageProcessors to `ip1` and `ip2`.

---

When cross-posting like this, please always include links to the other posts, so people finding this question later will have a chance to follow the discussion.

Answer (score -1):

circle crop: https://youtu.be/OyiOFh1pD3k

resize: https://youtu.be/N_jddMMhzqc

combine both code.